# Rubyのopen-uriの400 Bad Request対策について(Internet archive(archive.org)へのアクセスについて)

Tags: ruby

Rubyのopen-uriを用いて、[Internet archive](https://web.archive.org/)のhttps://web.archive.org/web/20150421015448/http://www.google.com/とhttps://web.archive.org/web/20150408183138/https://suumo.jp/tochi/tokyo/sc_nishitokyo/nc_84783830/にアクセスしているのですが、googleのアーカイブには正しくアクセスできるものの、もう一つのURLは"400 Bad Request"が返っています。
また、アクセスするURLによっては、成功したり失敗したりすることもあります。

下記のサイトでは、"400 Bad Requestは殆どの場合ユーザー側に問題がある。"とありましたので対策を考えているのですが、open-uriを使用する際にTIPSがありますでしょうか。
情報ありましたら、教えていただけると助かります。

400 Bad Request
http://www.bmoo.net/archives/2012/02/312554.html

なお使用しているRubyは、2.2になります。
ruby 2.2.0preview1 (2014-09-17 trunk 47616) [x86_64-darwin14]
=====/ソースコード

```
require 'open-uri'

def rescue_open(url)
  rescue_num = 0
  begin
    res = open(url)
  rescue => e
    print "error raise in rescue: "
    p e
    print "url = #{url}\n"
    if rescue_num < 5 then
      sleep 1
      rescue_num = rescue_num + 1
      retry
    else
      res = nil
    end
  end
  puts "open OK url = #{url}\n\n" unless res == nil
  res
end

f = rescue_open('https://web.archive.org/web/20150421015448/http://www.google.com/')

f = rescue_open('https://web.archive.org/web/20150408183138/https://suumo.jp/tochi/tokyo/sc_nishitokyo/nc_84783830/')
```

========/実行結果
open OK url = https://web.archive.org/web/20150421015448/http://www.google.com/

error raise in rescue: #
url = https://web.archive.org/web/20150408183138/https://suumo.jp/tochi/tokyo/sc_nishitokyo/nc_84783830/
error raise in rescue: #
url = https://web.archive.org/web/20150408183138/https://suumo.jp/tochi/tokyo/sc_nishitokyo/nc_84783830/
error raise in rescue: #
url = https://web.archive.org/web/20150408183138/https://suumo.jp/tochi/tokyo/sc_nishitokyo/nc_84783830/
error raise in rescue: #
url = https://web.archive.org/web/20150408183138/https://suumo.jp/tochi/tokyo/sc_nishitokyo/nc_84783830/
error raise in rescue: #
url = https://web.archive.org/web/20150408183138/https://suumo.jp/tochi/tokyo/sc_nishitokyo/nc_84783830/
error raise in rescue: #
url = https://web.archive.org/web/20150408183138/https://suumo.jp/tochi/tokyo/sc_nishitokyo/nc_84783830/

Answer (score 4):

気になったので open-uri.rb を読んでみました。(2.2.0に付属のものですが、2.2.0preview1でも同じはずです。)

次の流れで Bad request になっているようです。

1. open-uri は内部でリダイレクト処理を行う
2. リダイレクト時、web.archive.org は規格 (HTTP/1.1) に反してLocationに相対URLを入れて返してくる
3. そのような不正なレスポンスでも、open-uriは頑張って絶対URLに変換しようとする
4. 絶対URLに変換する際、連続した `/` が1個の `/` に変換されてしまう。(Rubyにおける "uri" の仕様; URLとしても連続した `/` は本来正しくない…はず。)

   ```
   例:
   URI("http://example.jp/") + URI("/foo//bar")
   => #<URI::HTTP:0x007f94dc0b5c70 URL:http://example.jp/foo/bar>
   ```
5. 結果的に web.archive.org が想定しているものと異なったURL (途中の `https://suumo.jp` が `https:/suumo.jp` になっている) をリクエストしてしまう。
6. web.archive.org が Bad Request を返す。

本来は open-uri の実装で問題無く利用できるはずですが、規格に適合しないサーバ (現実にはよくある) を利用する場合は net/http など別のライブラリを利用するのが良さそうです。

※open-uri は認証+リダイレクト周りでもちょっとクセがあったりするので、注意が必要です。(参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763399/openuri-causing-401-unauthorized-error-with-https-url/13765887#13765887)

Comment: 丁寧に調べていただきありがとうございます。
大変勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

上記urlにFirefoxでアクセスするとurlが書き換わるので、多分3xxの応答にopen-uriが対応していないように思われます。
　open処理を[ここ](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/library/net=2fhttp.html)を参考にNet::HTTPで書き換えると、上記urlでもうまく動作するようになりました。
　また、クロールするならMechanizeを使ったほうが色々楽だと思います。（[参考](http://www.xmisao.com/2013/10/05/ruby-www-mechanize.html)）

余談ですが、Ruby 2.2系列は2.2.2が出ていますので、特に理由がなければ最新のものに更新したほうがいいと思います。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
教えていただいた方法で試してみます。